# Chrome developer tool freezes

Tags: developer-tools, chrome-debugging

I'm unable to debug my web page on local host. On opening the developer tool,and clicking the source tab.. It gets hang/freeze. For other sites like YouTube.. It's working fine. I read somewhere it's something to do with setting previousviewedfiles in developer tool. Please help!